# Affine, surjective map between convex sets

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

The setup for my question is the following:
I have a compact and convex subset $K$ of some locally convex topological vector space. Within $K$ there is a $T\subset K$ which is compact and convex and contains more than one point. Now there is an affine, surjective, continuous function $f:K\rightarrow T$ with the property that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in T$. The set of extreme points of $K$ is $\text{ex}(K)$ and of $T$ is $\text{ex}(T)$.

Is it true that $\text{ex}(T)\subset\text{ex}(K)$?
I can't think of a simple counterexample, can you help? If the answer is negative, can I obtain more than just $\text{ex}(T)\subset f(\text{ex}(K))$? Hope it's not too silly, much thanks for help!

Comment: And lets assume that the set $T$ conatins at least two extremepoints, because otherwise counterexample is easy: If $T$ contains only one point $t\in K$, which is not an extremepoint, on can take the constant map $f(x)=t$. What happens if the set $T$ is not trivial? If you need you can assume that everything is Choquetsimplex and the extremesets are measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Let $K$ be a right circular cylinder, let $T$ be one of its circular cross-sections (not the top and not the base, but one somewhere in the middle), and let $f$ be the orthogonal projection.  All relative boundary points of $T$ are extreme, but none are extreme in $K$.

(This example generalizes somewhat, in that if you are given $T$ and $f$, you can construct a (possibly oblique) cylinder $K$ by extending $T$ in the direction of the kernel of $f$.  This way all points of $T$ are extended to line segments, and so become non-extreme.)